# Why use に in 元気にしてたか？

Tags: grammar, translation

I learned that the particle に is meant to mark the place in a phrase, similar to *in, on and at*. But today I was reading Yotsubato and I came across this phrase **元気にしてたか** and obviously this rule doesn't apply to 元気.

It didn't stop me to understand the conversation (at least I think so), I presume it meant something like:

> How you doing? Good?

Am I wrong in this? Why use the particle に in this phrase?

Comment: `the particle に` -- 元気に could be analyzed as the continuative form (連用形) of na-adjective 元気な... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

元気　is a na adjective

To describe the verb　していた（する), we add に to make 元気an adverb.

Comment: I suppose it works for all na-adjectives. But what about i-adjectives?

Comment: @JoãoBrgai for い-adjectives, no particle is used. Instead, the い at the end of the word becomes く. *Example:* **やさしく**してください。